# Position at central workspace on login

Tags: compiz, workspaces

I have set up 3x3 workspace switcher, and I want my position to be on the central one by default. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to Marco, I have figured out a way using `wmctrl`.

Because compiz workspaces are actually viewport of a single desktop, so the solution is to move the current viewport to cover the center region of the desktop.

First, call `wmctrl -d` to get the information of current desktop:

```
read desktop_id _ast \
    DG_ geometry \
    VP_ viewport \
    WA_ wa_off wa_size \
    title \
    < <(LANG=C wmctrl -d | grep '*')

geom_w=${geometry%x*}
geom_h=${geometry#*x}

# The workarea size isn't accurate, because the top/bottom panel is excluded. 
viewport_w=${wa_size%x*}
viewport_h=${wa_size#*x}

rows=$((geom_w / viewport_w))
cols=$((geom_h / viewport_h))

# Fix the viewport size
viewport_w=$((geom_w / rows))
viewport_h=$((geom_h / cols))
```

Then, calculate the origin of the center viewport:

```
center_row=$((rows / 2))
center_col=$((cols / 2))

center_x=$((center_col * viewport_w))
center_y=$((center_row * viewport_h))

center_viewport=$center_x,$center_y
```

And move the viewport there:

```
wmctrl -o $center_viewport
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes: install [wmctrl](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wmctrl)

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
```

and create a file in `~/.config/autostart/wmctrl.desktop` with the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Desktop Switcher
Exec=/usr/bin/wmctrl -s 4
Type=Application
```

Comment: There's only one desktop in compiz. But `wmctrl` can switch viewport within the desktop anyway. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

1. First download this [helper script [image]](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Dbus?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=compiz-send.py) for controlling compiz from the command line. Save it as `compiz-send.py` in your home folder.
2. Run the command `python compiz-send.py vpswitch switch_to_5_key` to make sure it works correctly. It should switch you to the center workspace.
3. If it works, create a file called `.switch_to_center_workspace.sh` in your home folder and paste the following inside of it:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   sleep 5 && python /home/user/compiz-send.py vpswitch switch_to_5_key
   ```

   replacing `user` with your username.
4. Open up Startup Applications, *System -> Preferences -> Startup Applications*.
5. Click *Add* and in the *Command:* entry put `/home/user/.switch_to_center_workspace.sh`. Put whatever you want in the *Name:* and *Comment:* entries.
6. Log out and log back in and verify that it works.

Comment: Unfortunately the script doesn't work `dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "activate" with signature "si" on interface "org.freedesktop.compiz" doesn't exist`

Comment: @谢继雷 Change the `sleep 5` part of the script to a higher number like `sleep 10` to make sure compiz is already running when the script is run. You are using compiz right?

Comment: I try to run the script in gnome-terminal, and get the exception. I'm using compiz 0.8.6.

Comment: In the script, it's said the method signature "si" doesn't exist, so I guess the arguments (string, int) passed to activate() may not correct..

Answer (score 2):

I was going to ask the similar question, but for 3 horizontal workspaces and I'm also running compiz, and the `wmctrl -d` output (per workspace) looks like this:

- At Workspace 1: `0  * DG: 4098x768  VP: 0,0  WA: 0,24 1366x744  Workspace 1`
- At Workspace 2: `0  * DG: 4098x768  VP: 1366,0  WA: 0,24 1366x744  Workspace 1`
- At Workspace 3: `0  * DG: 4098x768  VP: 2732,0  WA: 0,24 1366x744  Workspace 1`

Than I simply used `wmctrl -o 1366,0` (**VP** values) to make the center as my default workspace at startup. Might not work for everyone, but just in case ;)

Comment: The command I'm using in "System -> Preferences -> Startup Applications": `sh -c "sleep 2;/usr/bin/wmctrl -o 1366,0`

Comment: ...you might need to adjust sleep value, e.g. try 10, 15, etc.

Comment: Thanks for this note - sorry I didn't read it before reading your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a brief note - I'm using Natty, and thanks to @谢继雷's answer, I noticed that the following is reported by moving the terminal in each of the four 'workspaces' in Unity:

```
$ wmctrl -d
# top left
0  * DG: 2048x1200  VP: 0,0  WA: 0,24 1024x576  Workspace 1
# bottom left
0  * DG: 2048x1200  VP: 0,600  WA: 0,24 1024x576  Workspace 1
# top right
0  * DG: 2048x1200  VP: 1024,0  WA: 0,24 1024x576  Workspace 1
# bottom right 
0  * DG: 2048x1200  VP: 1024,600  WA: 0,24 1024x576  Workspace 1
```

... i.e. they are not neither separate desktops, nor workspaces - simply the viewport changes!

So, to change between those four viewports, simply call the `wmctrl -o` command directly with the `VP` values listed above, i.e.:

```
wmctrl -o 0,0
wmctrl -o 0,600
wmctrl -o 1024,0
wmctrl -o 1024,600
```

EDIT: Ups, sorry, just saw this is the same as @wik's answer - merge/delete as appropriate..